# iOS - PayPal integration - "Invalid parameter Subtotal" error

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I tried to integrate PayPal in my iPhone app. But when I tap the "pay with paypal" button for the sandbox enviornment, if the total amount is greater than $10,000 an alert showing "Invalid parameter subTotal" is displaying.

If the total amount is less than $10,000 the app displaying the view of PayPal correctly.

Can anyone please suggest the reason of this issue?

Comment: In my case, the maximum transaction amount < $9000!

Answer (score 1):

PayPal will reject any transaction of $10,000 USD. The limit varies country by country and also depends on if the user is "verified." Apparently you can't even use PayPal for transactions over $10,000 on eBay.